# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument in rokomari.com

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

In the web scrapping in python, I face this problem. Please help me to solve my problem. I am totally new in python programming.[image]

How can I solve this problem easily

Comment: The problem is that you have a positional argument, `XPATH`, following the keyword argument `by=By` but before `value = '...'`. All keyword arguments must follow the last positional argument. What arguments did you *intend* to pass to `find_element`? It's not clear if you have arguments out of order, or some other issue with passing just two keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.
It should be

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "your_xpath_expression")
```

It should be a dot `.` after `By`, not a comma